# Google Websmaster Tools crawl errors reporting a link that does not exist

Tags: google-search-console, links, crawl-errors, broken-links

Google Webmaster Tools seems to be giving me an erroneous report. The crawl Errors (Smart Phone tab) still shows a link to http://mypubguide.com/good-pubs/Blacko from http://mypubguide.com/good-pubs/blacko-in-pendle-district

I cannot find any such link when I view source or use web kit to search for it. This been going on for a while but this comes back after being marked as fixed and it's on the report as being detected today.

Caching policy in the web.config is set to 30 minutes:

Comment: Google sometimes finds things that it "thinks" are links.  It may treat something like `var foo = '/Blacko';` in JavaScript as if it were a URL.  I don't see anything like that in your page now, but that report has a tendency to report links it may have found months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Google is saying, "Hey, it used to be there but it isn't anymore so you obviously need to fix this!" And when you mark it as "fixed", they check again and it's still not there so they say, "Hey, it used to be there but it isn't anymore so you obviously need to fix this!"

The only way to really fix it is to respond to it with a 301 or 302 and redirect to a different page, like home. How does the URI respond right now?

I don't recall but, when this happens to me, I redirect with a 301 for a while and Google understands that and the problem goes away.

**EDIT:** I just looked and I respond with a 410. I don't remember why I used 410 so I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I've been responding with 410 for months... It still won't go away :)